# Streaming music from dropbox to iPad

Tags: ipad, music, dropbox

Is there really no way to stream music from dropbox to iPad and play MORE THAN ONE song at once and without giving third parties (Boxytunes etc) my dropbox password?

Comment: How are you doing it now? Does the iPad DropBox client play music? ...Actually, for that matter, how is it possible to **play** "more than one song at once" (i.e. simultaneously) on any personal computer or mobile device ever created in the history of the world? Please clarify what you're actually asking. :)

Answer (score 1):

Mc Loud uses oAuth authentication. This means that your password is not seen by the App, but entered on an internet page of Dropbox. Mc Loud only gets an anonymous token from Dropbox that you can revoke at any time in your Dropbox account.

http://mcloud.tunesremote.com

Mc Loud Remote (a free download) can be used in Demo mode to test all features of Mc Loud.

Features are:
- universal (iPod touch, iPhone, iPad)
- stream music and videos directly from Dropbox
- includes a remote that lets you control Mc Loud either from any web browser or from Mc Loud Remote on another iOS device
- fast indexing of all metadata, including title, album, artist, duration, composer, genre and album art
- control from the lock screen